# StackOverFlowException when creating new instance of class unless it's an array

Tags: c#

I'm making changes to an app that I was creating multiple instances of the Class1 object and now I only need one. I started getting overflow exceptions so I created a bare project. Also, if I change Class1 : Form1 to just Class1, it works but I don't understand why I need to do that.

Form1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1[] temp = new Class1[5]; // works
    Class1 temp = new Class1(); // stack overflow exception
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Class1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
class Class1 : Form1
{

}
}
```

Comment: One is an array initialization, the other is instantiating a new class object that calls itself.

Comment: Since Class1 is inheriting from Form1, when you instantiate a new Class1, the code to initialize a new Form1 is also run. That creates a new Class1 which creates a new Class1 which creates a new Class1. So you make an infinite amount of Class1 and there's not room for that on the stack.

Comment: You have an infinite loop: (1) Create an instance of `Form1`. (2) As part of `Form1` being created, create `Class1` (to fill the `temp` variable). (3) `Class1` is a subclass of `Form1`, so create another instance of `Form1`. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you run out of memory. What are you actually trying to do, and why is it important that `Class1` inherits from `Form1`?

Comment: @JoeSewell There is *no* loop.

Comment: Class1 is a subclass of Form1. Form1 has a Class1 instance that gets created at construction time. That will create a new Form1 (running that constructor). Presto, stack overflow. When you create the array, the array is filled with nulls (so no constructors are run). You need to figure out what this means and what you want to do. At the very least, you need to move the initialization of `temp` out of the constructor

Comment: @TanveerBadar Very well, an infinite sequence of steps which repeats.

Comment: @TanveerBadar there is a data loop, or cycle. Or put another way this is a recursive data structure with no way of terminating. Like a recursive function with no exit condition

Comment: Oh jeez, I can't believe I was overlooking that. I guess the reason why I'm having the subclass inherit is to get access to an enum that I have in my base class.

Comment: Hence you should avoid declaring enums _inside classes_, but instead declare enums in a _namespace_, next to and at the same level as the classes.  Exception being for private enums, but if they're private, you weren't supposed to need them outside that class.  ;)

Comment: When you create the array you're not actually making instances of Class1 as you're not initializing them. If you look in debug mode you can see that they're all null, so that's why it doesn't crash.

Comment: Thank you all for your guidance! Got it straight now as well as the enum!